# Lists Should Be Equal in robot framework is not working with python3.7

Tags: robotframework, python-3.7

I updated my python from python2.7 to python3.7 and My robot framework is also 3. I am getting error while list comparison. I also tried

Lists Should Be Equal   ${a}    ${b}    ignore_order=True

but I am getting below issue -

Lists are different:
Index 0: max != min
Index 1: min != max

Comment: You forgot to give two sample lists for us to reproduce. How can we help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i was digging it and i found that the test was comparing dictionaries. So if i m testing it with python3 then i have to give Dictionaries should be equal, but with python2 it also works with Lists should be equal

Comment: Good that you found the answer when preparing the sample data to show us.